# Classifying bifurcation points to this dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, self-learning, bifurcation

I have the one-dimensional dynamical system $\dot x = f(x)$ where

$$f(x) = (x^2-1)^2-\mu^2$$

And I am asked to find the bifurcation points, draw the bifurcation diagram and classify the points.

So I know to find the bifurcation points I need to find the points $(\mu^*,x^*)$ such that

$$(x^2-1)^2-\mu^2 \\ 4x(x^2-1) = 0$$

and these points are $(1,0)$, $(-1,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(0,-1)$

Then drawing the bifurcation diagram I find something that looks like this

[image]

Now, I know one way to classify the bifurcation points is to find which conditions they satisfy

i.e $\frac{df}{du}$, $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}$, $\frac{d^2f}{dudx}$, $\frac{d^3f}{d^3x}$

but I was wondering if there was another way to find them by just looking at the Bif diagram.

So my thinking here would be to say the bifurcation points at $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ are clearly saddle nodes and at $(0,1)$ and $(0-1)$ are transcritical.

Would I be correct in thinking this? Or should I just see which conditions each point satisfies.

Comment: A hint:  Forget about derivatives, etc. Just draw the graph of $(x^2-1)^2$ and shift it downwards by $\mu^2$. What will be the mutual positions of the zeros of the shifted function depending on $\mu$?  (A further hint: consider $\mu=0$, $\mu\in(0,1)$, $\mu=1$ and $\mu>1$.)

Comment: I don't see how that allows me to classify the bifurcation points though.

Comment: For instance: if $\mu=1$, you have an asymptotically stable (hyperbolic) equilibrium at $x=-\sqrt{2}$, an unstable from the left and asymptotically stable from the right (nonhyperbolic) equilibrium at $x=0$, and an unstable (hyperbolic) equilibrium at $x=\sqrt{2}$. When $\mu>1$, both hyperbolic equilibria remain (only change their locations), but the nonhyperbolic equilibrium disappears. Do you know what happens when $\mu<1$ but is close to $1$? There should be four equilibria then.

Comment: Ok I understand that but I don't get how that tells me if the bifurcation point is transciritical or saddle or pitchfork. I know there are 4 bifurcation points, but what I want to know is how do I say if theyre transcritical etc

Comment: If you know that when $\mu$ increases through $1$, two equilibria (one asymptotically stable and one unstable) collide and annihilate each other, what sort of bifurcation that is? Don't you know the name?

Comment: I actually don't. That's not how I have learnt them. You're talking about equilibrium at $x = \sqrt{2}$ when that isn't even one of the bif points I found

Comment: Please see [Saddle-node bifurcation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle-node_bifurcation) (actually, in my comment I just used an expression from that Wikipedia article), and other articles on bifurcation.